# Running html5 app template in ubuntu sdk failed?

Tags: sdk, ubuntu-14.04, html5-apps

My configuration :

```
Ubuntu 14.04 LTS
64bit
Qtcreator 3.1.1
everything is up-to-date
```

Hello everyone,
I'm trying to just compile and run an HTML5 App for ubuntu Phone, but after trying and searching for a week now, I still can't make it run !
For the moment I just want to run the simple html5 app template.

This is the situation :

- I have installed ubuntu sdk as instructed in https://developer.ubuntu.com/en/start/ubuntu-sdk/installing-the-sdk/
- I've created in the run click menu, an i386 build target. (15.04) --- which exited with no errors
- I created an i386 emulator in devices --> i386 - devel - default password --- which is finally up and running correctly

The problem is when I compile the default template : theses are the errors I get :

1. desktop_Exec(app): found unexpected Exec with architecture 'all':./qtc_device_debughelper.py
2. security_policy_groups_safe_app(debug):(REJECT)reserved policy group 'debug':not for production use
3. security_policy_version_matches_framework(app.apparmor):invalid framework 'ubuntu-core-15.04'

And when I try to edit it anyway : 
This is what I get :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/qtc_device_applaunch.py", line 29, in <module>
gi.Repository.get_default().require("UbuntuAppLaunch")
gi.RepositoryError: Typelib file for namespace 'UbuntuAppLaunch' (any version) not found

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2158, in _find_spec
AttributeError: 'DynamicImporter' object has no attribute 'find_spec'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/tmp/qtc_device_applaunch.py", line 33, in <module>
from gi.repository import UpstartAppLaunch as UAL
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/gi/importer.py", line 53, in find_module
'introspection typelib not found' % namespace)
ImportError: cannot import name UpstartAppLaunch, introspection typelib not found
```

I have been looking for this everywhere but I couldn't find something that works. 
I need some of your knowledge to help me understand all this!

Comment: You may want to ask at http://askubuntu.com/

Answer (score 0):

I have the same errors. I think that the 'ubuntu-core-15.04'-error is related to the version of Ubuntu you are using. I use Mint 17, which is based on Ubuntu 14.04. Canonical recommends the newer Ubuntu Versions for app-developing, because there is some stuff in it they changed.

unfortunately, I can't help you with the other errors.